# Каптча и сессия

Tags: php, сессия, captcha

Проверка на неверность каптчи происходит так:

```
if($_POST['captcha_code'] != $_SESSION['csession_code']) {
 echo 'Неверный код безопасности';
}
```

Всё хорошо. Но проблема в том, если к примеру послать с другого сайта прямой запрос PHP на мой сайт, то каптча спокойно обойдётся, так как при прямом запросе с другого сайта **сессия не видится**. Получается примерно так, при отправке запроса с другого сайта:

> '' != ''

Как решается данная проблема?

Comment: Ну так проверьте, существует ли сессия. В чем проблема?

Comment: @lampa, сделал проверку. А если кто-то допустим захочет прямой запрос послать, а там будет код безопасности. Он сможет передать параметр и пройти? Ведь сессии вроде не ловятся...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_POST['captcha_code'] != $_SESSION['csession_code'] && !empty($_POST['captcha_code'])
```

Comment: поменяйте местами условие, и добавьте в начало isset($_SESSION['csession_code']) иначе будет notify

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['csession_code']))  
   if(!($_POST['captcha_code'] == $_SESSION['csession_code']))
      echo 'Неверный код безопасности';
```

Comment: @Node_pro, а если сессии нет, то и каптчу не запросит. Ужс.